# How to enumerate inside form

Tags: enumerate, forms

I am trying to create a task list wherein I can mark if a task is done or not using check boxes. I am using `CheckBox` from `Form` for that.
Now I want to enumerate those tasks. Part of my `Latex` content is here -

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\noindent
Tasks:\\               
\begin{enumerate}
\item \CheckBox[bordercolor={0 0 0},height=1ex,width=1.5ex]{task1}\quad \\
\item \CheckBox[bordercolor={0 0 0},height=1ex,width=1.5ex]{task2}\quad \\
\item \CheckBox[bordercolor={0 0 0},height=1ex,width=1.5ex]{task3}\quad \\
\item \CheckBox[bordercolor={0 0 0},height=0.5ex,width=1.5ex]{task4}\quad \\
\end{enumerate} 
\end{Form}
\end{document}
\end
```

But it doesn't work! I don't why it doesn't put numbers before tasks.

Comment: Also even with equal height and width, I don't see square check boxes. How can I get square check boxes?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: After suppressing the line changing commands and processing your document (with `hyperref` loaded), this is what I get (using Okular as viewer): http://imgur.com/sfYJJLY Do you get something different? If so, which viewer do you use?

Comment: @tohecz edited my tex content.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes I get a different output. I don't see numbered tasks. I am using ubuntu's document viewer to open it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/) the `minimal` class doesn't define the basic structures for typesetting a document: it just leaves almost everything undefined. No size changing command, no specific definition for `\labelenumi` and similar commands.

It's easy to see this with `texdef`:

```
$ texdef -t latex -c minimal labelenumi

\labelenumi:
undefined
```

The command is used to print the item number; the LaTeX run doesn't report an `Undefined control sequence` error, because `\csname...\endcsname` is used.

If you simply change `minimal` to `article`, you get what you want. If you don't want page numbers, add `\pagestyle{empty}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\noindent
Tasks:\\
\begin{enumerate}
\item \CheckBox[bordercolor={0 0 0},height=1ex,width=1.5ex]{task1}
\item \CheckBox[bordercolor={0 0 0},height=1ex,width=1.5ex]{task2}
\item \CheckBox[bordercolor={0 0 0},height=1ex,width=1.5ex]{task3}
\item \CheckBox[bordercolor={0 0 0},height=0.5ex,width=1.5ex]{task4}
\end{enumerate}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked! One more small thing - even with equal height and width, I don't see square check boxes. uneven check boxes are appearing. How can I get square check boxes?

Comment: @HussainTamboli They look square to me

Comment: Try some other items instead of task1, task2, task3, etc. For eg. one of my tasks is "Bring all templates in one place". and for that it looks like a rectangle with height > width

Comment: @HussainTamboli Sorry, but I don't understand. On the other hand this has nothing to do with the subject of your question; if you have other problems, please make a new question.